# postPersist event not updating database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, persistence, listener

I have 2 entities, Invoice and Advance. Advances are related to Invoices, with ManyToOne relation. And when adding or editing and advance, I want the Invoice total to be edited accordingly. I have a listener set for Advances postPersist which looks like this :

```
class PostPersistListener
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();

        // Advance Listener
        if ($entity instanceof Advance) {

            // Modification du total de la facture mère
            $invoice = $entity->getInvoice();

            echo '<pre>';
            \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($invoice);
            echo '</pre>';

            $newTotal = $invoice->getTotalMaster() - $entity->getTotalMaster();
            $invoice->setTotalMaster($newTotal);

            echo '<pre>';
            \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($invoice);
            echo '</pre>';

            $em->flush();

        }

    }
}
```

The event is well triggered. The first dump() displays something like this :

```
object(stdClass)#1379 (49) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(32) "Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Invoice"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["totalMaster"]=>
  float(250)
}
```

And the second dump() this :

```
object(stdClass)#1379 (49) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(32) "Evo\BackendBundle\Entity\Invoice"
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["totalMaster"]=>
  float(240)
}
```

So the "totalMaster" property is modified. But the $em->flush() doesn't seem to update the field in the database. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 3):

To start with, as it's name implies, PostPersist only get's triggered after the initial persist operation i.e. only for new objects.  Editing an existing object will not trigger the event.

From: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events

```
postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the entity has been made persistent. 
It will be invoked after the database **insert** operations. 
Generated primary key values are available in the postPersist event.
```

There are also strict limits to what you can do with these events.  Basically the flush operation is already underway so anything that updates an entity is problematical at best.  Specifically:

From: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist

```
The three post events are called inside EntityManager#flush(). 
Changes in here are not relevant to the persistence in the database, 
but you can use these events to alter non-persistable items, like non-mapped fields, logging or 
even associated classes that are directly mapped by Doctrine.
```

It's barely possible you might get this to work using prePersist and preUpdate but those have their own issues.

@kix has the correct approach.  Updating an invoice total is a domain function and should be handled using a domain event.

P.S.  You don't need to call persist on existing objects retrieved through Doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the `$em->persist($invoice)` line.

Also, I'd suggest implementing this logic with Symfony's built-in events, not with `prePersist` listeners. The simple reason behind this is that your code is dealing with business logic and not persistence logic. You should dispatch an `AdvanceModified` event with the `event_dispatcher` service (it should be available to your controller) and then process it in a listener.

Comment: I thought persist() method wasn't meant to be called on update, if I refer to the SF doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#updating-an-object. Anyway, i'll take a look at the built-in events, as you advised me.

Comment: I'm not sure that the entity you get from the event args is correctly managed.

Comment: I'm starting to read some doc about built-in events, and i'll implement this for my invoice total calculation. And what about setting a reference field in my invoice/advance when its status is set to 1 ? Is this more a business or persistence logic ?

Comment: @VaN, well, if your invoices should reference some other entity when their status matches a rule, then it's business logic.
You should use `prePersist` listeners only when you're dealing with the underlying data and its persistence logic, like in `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` (https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md#doctrine-extension-listener-services)